# twitter bootstrap modal vs. PHP POST request through javascript-ajax

Tags: javascript, php, forms, twitter-bootstrap

why the code below doesn't do its job ? 
I just need POST via javascript id content on click btn.
this code works properly in many other situations but not here that i'm using twitter bootstrap modal.
thanks.

```
<button id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-warning" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> delete id
    </button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  //delete id
  $(document).on('click','.btn-warning',function(){ 
    var element = $(this);
    var del_id = element.attr("id");
    var info = 'id=' + del_id;

    if(confirm("are you sure ?")){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "page.php",
        data: info,
        success: function(){ window.location.href = "/logout.php"; }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
</script>

PHP
if($_POST['id']){

      $id=$_POST['id'];
      $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
...
```

Comment: what happens if you bind the event directly to the selected class? like: `$(".btn-warning").on('click',function(){`

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: @EduLomeli nothing happened

Comment: @vladkras just the predictable Notice: Undefined index: id in ...

Comment: the bind event is ok, so the `id` attr is getting well? `console.log(del_id)`

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should be using isset(variable) in the PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['ID'])
{
    ...
```

Second, it doesn't work because you need to set the data and a key -> value array.

```
data: {id: "ID_NUMBER"}
```

Look over the examples on Jquery's site: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

I would also suggest using a unique ID property or a new/unique class proverty, and then using that to add the onClick event.

Comment: I just need POST via javascript id content on click button.

Answer (score 0):

```
info = {'id' :  del_id };
```

Try to send data as array.